# Which is better 'recent impressive incidents' or 'impressive recent incidents'?

Tags: adjective-order

When I practiced writing in English, the order between the adjectives were so confusing.
I have ever heard that the order of adjectives in the sentence is determined by the meaning of each, but I don't know this perfectly. I'll appreciate it if anyone answer this question.

Which is better : 'recent impressive incidents' or 'impressive recent incidents'

Comment: The order of the adjectives determines meaning of the sentence. Neither sentence is better. Each has a different meaning. The first sentence places the emphasis upon the recent nature of the events; the second sentence places the emphasis upon their impressive nature.

Comment: As @FeliniusRex states, this is not intrinsically order dependent, as would be "one old red car," which would never have the adjectives in another order.